# Why is the address the same every time?

Tags: zig

I wrote a function with a local variable "arr". I thought its stack address should be different every time the function executes, but it doesn't.

```
const std = @import("std");

fn hello() void {
  var arr: [100]u8 = undefined;
  // Why is the address the same every time?
  std.debug.print("{*}\n", .{&arr});
}

pub fn main() void {
  hello();
  hello();
  hello();
}
```

the output looks like this:

```
[100]u8@7fff0c1a4ef4
[100]u8@7fff0c1a4ef4
[100]u8@7fff0c1a4ef4
```

I tried on godbolt, you can try it yourself:
https://godbolt.org/z/133aEh4Tz

Comment: Why would it be different?  You're calling the function from exactly the same context each time.  Have some of the calls to `hello()` be from another function, rather than called directly from `main()`, and you should see different addresses.

Comment: If returning from a function and then calling it again meant that *different* memory was allocated the second time, many programs would run out of stack memory quickly and crash.

Comment: @jasonharper Yes, indeed. Thanks. I'm new to low level languages. I think I should learn something new.